# How to turn "with", "and", "together", and related words/constructs into verbs or nouns?

Tags: vocabulary

I am trying to have every word have a corresponding noun and verb, to see if it's possible. Currently I am focusing on prepositions, which need some massaging for the conlang I'm working on, as I don't want a direct clone of English haha.

I'm currently wondering about the words like "with", "and", and "together". I would make them into the same verb like "join", and after thinking about it, I'm not sure how these words are really different! You say stuff like "red **together with** blue", but I don't get how to describe/delineate the true underlying meaning of these 3 or 4 (+join) words.

How could these 3 words (and potentially others) be nounified and/or verbified, and how would they at the same time retain their unique features (if there are any)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a definitive conceptual scheme for ensuring that prepositions all have cognate nouns and verbs.  Your way would work fine, but you should bear in mind that there are other schemes as well.  For example:

Root #1:

P = with (comitative)
Adv = together
Conj. = and
N = companion (widest definition)
V = accompany

Root #2:

P = with (instrumental)
Adj = useful, handy
Adv = usefully, handily
N = use /jus/
V = use /juz/

Root #3:

P = meaning "joined.to"
Adj. = joined, conjoined
N = juncture
V = join

Comment: Hey, Jim, shouldn't the nominal cognate of "with (comitative)" mean "accompaniment"?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a strategy for generally verbing nouns, then I recommend using it on prepositions' noun meanings. One such strategy might be making the (transitive) verb of a noun mean "to [the noun in question]-ify x."

Regarding noun meanings, those are usually simple enough. For example, the word for "with" might mean "thing that is used, tool", or "usage, use". The word of "like" might mean "similarity". The word for "and" (which is approximately equivalent in meaning to "together with") might mean "togetherness, withness".